# "Incomplete file" error downloading file with header in php

Tags: php, header, fwrite

I am using header in PHP in order to force downloading a text file. This is the code:

```
$file = fopen("download/file.txt",'w');
fwrite($file,"some text" . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header("Connection: close");
```

When I click the button, file is generated correctly, and I can open it in a text editor, but doesn't download because this: "Error: incomplete file". Where am I wrong?

Comment: You don't sent the actual file contents ;)

Comment: Agreed. All you've done is set a header. The file contents haven't been echo'd to the output. You don't actually need the fopen/fwrite/fclose bits here at all (unless you wish to preserve a copy of the downloaded contents on the server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. You are right, I had to add `readfile()` to my code. With this line at the end of the code it works good:

```
readfile($file);
```

Comment: `echo "some text"` would have achieved the same. Like I said above, you don't actually need a file on the server's disk, in order to download something as a file to the browser. The headers you sent cause the browser to turn the response content into a file (instead of displaying it in the web page).